# System.NullReferenceException on MySqlCommand

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to execute the same query on two different database, for doing this I've created two connection string in `My.Settings`. Now, the first function (that add the value in localhost), working well. See:

```
Dim query = "INSERT INTO text_app (name, last_name)
                                    VALUES(@namep, @last_namep)"

Dim MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, dbCon)

MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@namep", name.Text)
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_namep", last_name.Text)

MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Sync.SyncOut(MySqlCommand) 'Pass the object to another function
```

I pass the `MySqlCommand` to `SyncOut` function, this:

```
Using dbCon As MySqlConnection = establishWebConnection()

        Try
            dbCon.Open() 'Open connection..

            'Clone the previous used object for reusing it

            Dim MySqlCommand = query_command.Clone

            MySqlCommand.Connection = dbCon 'Pass the new connection

            MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 'Execute the query

            Return True 

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message)

        End Try

    End Using
```

Now `query_command` is `MySqlCommand` passed. The `dbCon` is another connection that get the online database (the connection doesn't have any problem's I can connect right to the online db). How you can see I open the connection, pass this to the command and after all I do `ExecuteNonQuery`, on this command I get:

> System.NullReference Exception

If I use `ex.Message` I can see the error in specific:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('calendar'.'text_app', CONSTRAINT 'text_app_ibfk_3' FOREIGN KEY ('id_services') REFERENCES 'text_service' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATED CASCADE)

I need to use again this command 'cause the two database must be updated in synch mode.

Comment: I had the same problem in the past, this happean that your web database structure need to update the id as the same for all table. In your local db you have different ID, so the problem's that you're referring to a "NULL", "NOTHING" in vb.net. You could set the ID in order as your table is set or think back your synch logic.

Comment: Please post the complete source of your method. Why are you using Clone with your command? What is the advatage?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use **MySql's Replication Feature** rather than updating two databases from code.